# MySQL Workbench 1:CN relationship

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, relationship

I'm currently practising SQL by building a database for an apartment rental system. In a first step I am designing an ER model in order to implement it in the next part. I want to draw a 1:CN relationship between customer and rating since a customer can give none, exactly one or multiple ratings, while each rating is dependent on exactly one customer. There are only 1:1, 1:N and N:M relationships displayed in the toolbar. Would the right choice be a non-identifying 1:N relationship?

Comment: For anybody who came along the same problem, I found the solution. Create a 1:N relationship and then right click it to edit the relationship. In the lower left corner, there is a field with the label foreign key. Click on it and untick the mandatory box. Now you have created a 1:CN relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think 1:N would be the right choice for Customer, Rating relationship since one particular customer can have multiple, one or no relationship.

Comment: But does the 1:N relationship include the possibility of a customer not having given a rating? As far as I know, there are special symbols to distinct between 1:N and 1:CN in Martin notation (the circle symbol) and UML (either 0..* or 1...*).